# Compute overlaping duration of events in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes: df_event_a
and df_event_b

One row corresponds to one event. There are two columns: start_ts and end_ts which are datetime.

I want to compute the daily duration (in for example seconds) for which there are two events at the same time.

Note that there might be within the same event, also overlapping duration. All that matters is an overlap between A and B: it means that the daily output CANNOT be greater than a duration of a day.

Example:

Event A:
2022-01-01 00:00:00 - 2022-01-01 10:00:00

2022-01-01 09:00:00 - 2022-01-01 12:00:00

Basically here, Event A covers 12 hours

Same logic for Event B and we should retrieve the duration for the intersect.

Thank you

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the logic to calculate the duration of intersection:

```
intersection_duration = max(min(eventA_end, eventB_end)-max(eventA_start, eventB_start),0).total_seconds()
```

Comment: The op says there "might" be an overlap. This only work if the overlap is guaranteed.

Comment: Assuming a starts before b starts, and ends before b ends... `(a_end - a_start) + (b_end - a_start) - MAX(a_end - b_start, 0)`

Comment: @MatBailie The logic does cover if there is no overlap. min(eventA_end, eventB_end)-max(eventA_start, eventB_start) will give a negative number if there is no overlap, and max((-ve),0) will be 0.